Show a random walk bridge from $-N$ to $N$, with standard normal steps, converges in law to a Brownian bridge on $(-1,1)$.
Consider a random walk on $[-N,N] \cap \mathbb{Z}$, with Gaussian step disribution $N(0,1)$, conditioned on being $0$ on the boundary. Denote this random walk by $h_N$. I have an exercise which I can't solve, which is to show that the process $\left \{\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} h_N(\lfloor{nt \rfloor}) \right \}_{t \in [-1,1]}$ converges in law to a Browninan Bridge on $[-1,1]$, in the sense of finite dimensioanl distributions. While intuitively this makes perfect sense, I wasn't able to formally prove this. I though that perhaps since both are Gaussian processes, it is sufficient to show that the covariance functions and the means converge. For the means it is obvious, but I couldn't write down explictly the covaraince function for $h_N$. Could someone provide some insights on the mastter?
